# Canonical Windows emulation question

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

Should we make this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24145/is-there-any-free-paid-windows-emulator-for-mac-os-x) into a canonical Windows question.

Either by putting each piece of software into an answer

or at least splitting the emulators (Virtual Box, Parallels and Fusion) native (Bootcamp) and Wine(Wine, Crossover, Wineskin etc) into separate answers with a more detailed explanation